# Why can't I load an Excel file automatically?

Tags: c#, excel

I'm currently developing a WFA that serves as a local database to a single person, it uses an Excel file (`.xlsx`) to feed data to the application, the application works without problems when loading the file manually via `OpenFileDialog`. However, the user must not be able to directly interact with the file, I tried loading the file at startup of the program from the fixed location:

```
C:\users\documents\application\Resources\db\tabla.xlsx
```

using this code:

```
string path = Application.StartupPath;
string file = @"Resources\db\tabla.xlsx";
string full = Path.Combine(path,file);
```

where `full` returns the desired path, however, I keep getting the following error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object

The error is caused by the workbook loading operation, the issue there is that the workbook tries to load even before the Form if initialized since most of my code was on the constructor of the form.

Here are both code snippets used to load the file manually and automatically:

Manual:

```
Using system.reflection;
Using Excel = Microsoft.office.interop.excel;

Public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Excel.application oXL;
    Excel._workbook oWB;
    Excel._worksheet oST;
    Object misvalue = system.reflection.missing.value;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.RestoreDirectory = true;

        MessageBox.Show("Selecciona la base de datos a usar (formato .XLS).");

        if (open.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            try
            {
                oXL = new Excel.Application();
                oXL.Visible = false;
                oXL.UserControl = true;

                oWB = (oXL.Workbooks.Open(open.FileName));
                oST = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.Sheets.get_Item("Sheet1");

                count = oST.Cells.Find("*", misvalue, misvalue, misvalue, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, false, misvalue, misvalue).Row;

                for (int x = 1; x < count; x++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(oST.Cells[x + 1, 1].value, oST.Cells[x + 1, 2].value, oST.Cells[x + 1, 3].value, oST.Cells[x + 1, 4].value, oST.Cells[x + 1, 5].value, oST.Cells[x + 1, 6].value);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ocurrio un error y la aplicacion no se pudo inicializar correctamente, asegurate que no haya una copia de la aplicacion en funcionamiento previo. El programa se cerrara ahora.");

                oXL.Quit();
                this.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ha fallado la seleccion de la base de datos, para continuar reinicie la aplicacion.");
        }
    }
}
```

Automatic:

```
Using system.reflection;
Using Excel = Microsoft.office.interop.excel;

Public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Excel.application oXL;
    Excel._workbook oWB;
    Excel._worksheet oST;
    Object misvalue = system.reflection.missing.value;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MessageBox.Show("Selecciona la base de datos a usar (formato .XLS).");

        try
        {
             oXL = new Excel.Application();
             oXL.Visible = false;
             oXL.UserControl = true;

             string path = Application.StartupPath;
             string file = @"Resources\db\tabla.xlsx";
             string full = Path.Combine(path,file);

             oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(full);
             oST = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.Sheets.get_Item("Sheet1");

             count = oST.Cells.Find("*", misvalue, misvalue, misvalue, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, false, misvalue, misvalue).Row;

             for (int x = 1; x < count; x++)
             {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(oST.Cells[x + 1, 1].value, oST.Cells[x + 1, 2].value, oST.Cells[x + 1, 3].value, oST.Cells[x + 1, 4].value, oST.Cells[x + 1, 5].value, oST.Cells[x + 1, 6].value);
             }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrio un error y la aplicacion no se pudo inicializar correctamente, asegurate que no haya una copia de la aplicacion en funcionamiento previo. El programa se cerrara ahora.");

            oXL.Quit();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I posted the same question on the Stack Overflow Spanish branch and I was suggested to use `ClosedXML`, which is actually a very good option and allows you to deal with this kind of issues way faster, but currently I need this to be able to be done just using the native Excel interop.

I have a couple of questions regarding this issue:

1. Am I correctly calling the file the way I do it?
   (Edit: Yes, the file calling method was correct, however it caused troubles in the try sentence it was inside of.)
2. Why does the error jumps when starting the application?
   (Edit: The error jumps when the action being performed on the constructor is faster than the form itself, fixed it by moving the code to the `Form_Load` event)

Here is the final code snippet:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ApplicationName
{ 
    public partial class Form : Form
    {
        int count;
        int count2;
        int count3;

        Excel.Application oXL;
        Excel._Workbook oWB;
        Excel._Worksheet oST;
        object misvalue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        public Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = Application.StartupPath;
            string file = @"Resources\db\tabla.xlsx";
            string full = Path.Combine(path, file);

                oXL = new Excel.Application();
                oXL.Visible = false;
                oXL.UserControl = true;

            try
            {
                oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(full);
                oST = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.Sheets.get_Item("Sheet1");
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ocurrio un error al cargar la base de datos, asegurate que exista en la carpeta DB en los archivos del programa.");
                MessageBox.Show("DEBUG: " + full);
                oXL.Quit();
                this.Close();
            }


            count = oST.Cells.Find("*", misvalue, misvalue, misvalue, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, false, misvalue, misvalue).Row;

                for (int x = 1; x < count; x++)
                {
                    dgv_tab1.Rows.Add(oST.Cells[x + 1, 1].value, oST.Cells[x + 1, 2].value, oST.Cells[x + 1, 3].value, oST.Cells[x + 1, 4].value, oST.Cells[x + 1, 5].value, oST.Cells[x + 1, 6].value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the stack trace.

Comment: A good amount of your casing looks off in the second example - is this actually compiled code?

Comment: Your code does not compile. In C# the keywords are in lower case. C# is case sensitive so `openfiledialog()` won't work; `OpenFileDialog()` will. And please indent your code correctly. It makes it easier to read.

Comment: Now your code has `try...catch...else`   Also `Excel._woorkbook oWB;` which looks off.  I understand these are "typos" but people generally avoid spending time on code which doesn't look like it will even compile.

Comment: `Excel._woorkbook` >> `Excel._workbook`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your code seems to be running in the constructor for the form.  The form fields have not been created yet.

Move your code into the `form_load` event and your code will work better.

Explanation: You will often get strange behavior with this programming approach.  The threading model for winforms is hard to explain sometimes.  Which is why it may work with your "manual" approach because of the delays, which allow the background thread to catch-up.

Comment: This fixed the issue while loading the file (the ObjectDisposedException), however, It couldnt load the file yet.

Comment: Finally fixed the issue, your approach was really helpful and made me realize what I was doing wrong. Im going to mark this as the answer and update the question content to match the actual solution.